# Resolving javascript files using webpack

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

My webpack.config.js contains something like:

```
...
module.exports = {
  entry: './app.js',
  output: { path: __dirname + "/dist/", filename: 'bundle.js' },
  resolve: {
    root: path.resolve('./js')
  }
  ....
}
```

The documentation suggests [resolve can have a root](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-root) value. But I get the error below.

```
$ node ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.resolve has an unknown property 'root'. These properties are valid:
   object { alias?, aliasFields?, cachePredicate?, descriptionFiles?, enforceExtension?, enforceModuleExtension?, extensions?, fileSystem?, mainFields?, mainFiles?, moduleExtensions?, modules?, plugins?, resolver?, symlinks?, unsafeCache?, useSyncFileSystemCalls? }
```

I get the same with modulesDirectories. Not sure which, or if either, I should be using. Any idea how I can pull my JS files in?

Answer (score 0):

You've looked at the documentation for webpack 1. Webpack 2 removed `resolve.root` and unified it to [`resolve.modules`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-modules), as shown in the [Migration Guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/) of the official webpack 2 docs.

The correct way of doing it with webpack 2 is:

```
resolve: {
  modules: [path.resolve('./js'), 'node_modules']
}
```

But you might have misunderstood what the option does. It **does not** include all the files in those paths. Webpack starts from your entry point and processes just the files that are being imported (see also [Core Concepts](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/)). So if you want webpack to include your JavaScript files, you need to import them at some point.

Instead this option tells webpack where to look for the module when you import it (not with a relative path). By default only `node_modules` is used for resolving [Module paths](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-resolution/#module-paths), just like Node.js does it.

For example with this directory structure:

```
js
├─ components
│   └─ main.js
└─ utils
    └─ helper.js
```

You can import the `helper.js` file from anywhere in your project with:

```
import helper from 'utils/helper';
```

Whereas if you didn't add `js/` to the `resolve.modules` you would need to import it with a relative path. So for instance in `js/components/main.js` the import would look like this:

```
import helper from '../utils/helper`;
```

Obviously the relative path is different depending on which directory you're in.

Comment: Thanks. If I do, say, `import map from 'js/map.js'` now where in my code I've done a `require(['js/map.js'])` I get `ERROR in ./app.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'js/map.js' in...`

Comment: That should be just `map.js` (remove the `js/`). Because when you import `js/map.js` with the `js/` added to `resolve.modules` it would look in `js/js/map.js` but that's not what you want.

Comment: If I remove the js/ I get twice as many errors. One for with and one for without js/

Comment: Well, I don't know your project structure. The simplest solution is to use relative paths, so you don't even need to configure anything.